# After death, does one experience the company of his loved ones in heaven?

Tags: death, mysticism-kabbalah, family-members, afterlife

Please provide sources, preferably kabbalistic.

Comment: Yes. Non-kabbalistic source, https://www.jewishpress.com/in-print/the-golden-leg/2017/10/23/, The following morning Rabbi Chanina said to his wife: “Are you satisfied that all the righteous people in Gan Eden should sit at tables which contain three legs while we should have a table containing only two legs? Do you realize we will be enjoying our reward in this world?”

Comment: related: [Do we get to be with our wife after we die?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86508/11501) - [Does a marriage last beyond death?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34126/11501)

Comment: thank you! I am also looking for sources about family members (and even friends or teachers) other than one's spouse...that is of particular interest to me

Comment: Yehuda FYI if you want to answer someone you need to preface your comment with @ and their username. That way the systems pings then and you can be sure they will see your comment

Comment: @Yehuda The gemoro in BB says about the meoras hamachpela that someone went there and saw Avrohom and Soroh together. (like in each others arms). Why are tsadikim buried with their wives. I dont think though everyone merits this.

Comment: I remember learning once that part of the process of a neshama returning to shamayim after death, is that it must 'watch' back its entire life with all its deceased relatives present, including any sins that it performed, and this ensuing embarrassment helps bring a teshuva.

Comment: @dov  I think it is a bit late for tshuva. Maybe you mean he is careful in his lifetime.

Comment: Not teshuva in the literal sense but rather helps cleanse the neshama so that it can ascend higher in the olam haemes